# change the privileges of opening a file when it has already jumped to a remote host using tramp

Tags: tramp, sudo

Good afternoon. To visit the local sudo privilege file, I use the tramp command:

```
Ctr+f //sudo::/путьКфайлу
```

Is it possible to open a remote file with sudo privileges if emacs already uses tramp, and the invitation to enter visiting the file looks like:

```
Ctr+f /ssh:remoteHost:/home/uzvr
```

It seems to me there should be a team to change the privileges of opening files when emacs is already working with deleted files. Thanks.

Thank you, Michael Albinus, you get a new jump, and you can’t use the fact that you already reached the host. I use an ssh certificate to access the host (it is written in the configuration file, thank you again for this personally), a third-party application forms the command (in this case, my command looks like this:

```el
/usr/local/bin/emacs -eval '
(progn
  (require (quote tramp-sh))
  (let ((args (assoc (quote tramp-login-args)
                     (assoc "ssh" tramp-methods))))
    (setcar (cdr args)
            (append (quote (("-F" "/home/alamd/ПакетыДоступа/al_kuhnia/config")))
                    (cadr args)))))' \
"/ssh:remoteHost: ~"
```

Next, emacs opens the user folder. It turns out then how can I transfer the configuration file for ssh again to tramp

Comment: n.b. This is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/2177687/324105

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Tramp's multi-hop:

```
C-x C-f /ssh:remoteHost|sudo:remotehost:/home/uzvr
```

The Tramp manual gives you more detail.

This will only work if you immediately attach my ssh configuration file for the trump, but I would like not to edit all files from root.only such a solution comes to mind

```el
M-: (progn
      (require (quote tramp-sh))
      (let ((args (assoc (quote tramp-login-args)
                         (assoc "ssh" tramp-methods))))
        (setcar (cdr args)
                (append (quote (("-F" "/home/alamd/ПакетыДоступа/al_kuhnia/config")))
                        (cadr args))))
      (find-file "/ssh:remoteHost|sudo:remotehost:/etc/ssh/sshd_config"))
```

Comment: did not fit into the comment, posted above

Comment: There's no need to edit all files as root. If you add the change-to-my-config-file form to your ~/.emacs. it shall work for both `/ssh:remoteHost:/home/uzvr` and `/ssh:remoteHost|sudo:remotehost:/home/uzvr`.